# Unable to update my cart file, getting the following error:Could not create working directory

Tags: xcode, terminal, carthage

I was trying to update my Cartfile using this comment: `Carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --use-ssh`
but I'm getting the following error after fetching and checking the frameworks:

```
.
.
*** Checking out ios-branch-deep-linking at "1.39.1"
*** Checking out Motion at "3.0.0"
Failed to check out repository into /Users/alijaber/Documents/myApp/Carthage/Checkouts/Cosmos: Could not create working directory (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “Carthage” couldn’t be saved in the folder “dgapp2-ios”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/alijaber/Documents/dgapp2-ios/Carthage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8977a63290 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory"}})
```

I tried to give Xcode full Disk access, but it didn't solve the issue.